# SwiftUI - iOS 13 UIViewRepresentable of WKWebView gets Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT crash

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to port WKWebView over to SwiftUI. Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebViewWrapper()
    }
}

/**
 WKWebView ported over to SwiftUI with `UIViewRepresentable`.
 */
final class WebViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    /// `UIViewRepresentable` required function #1.
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        print("make")
        let webView = WKWebView() /// EXC_BREAKPOINT error here
        return webView
    }
      
    /// `UIViewRepresentable` required function #2
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

That's it. I created a new SwiftUI project and pasted it in. However, I get this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

... with nothing printed in the console. This happened for both iOS 13.0 and iOS 13.1.

[image: Crashing on iOS 13]

**But, on iOS 14.2, it works fine.** The crash also seems to happen only for `WKWebView`. For example, if I replace it with `UITextView`, it runs without problems.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextViewWrapper()
    }
}

/**
 UITextView ported over to SwiftUI with `UIViewRepresentable`.
 */
final class TextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    /// `UIViewRepresentable` required function #1.
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView  {
        print("make")
        let textView = UITextView() /// no error, works fine
        return textView
    }
      
    /// `UIViewRepresentable` required function #2
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

[image: UITextView has no problems]

I'm running Big Sur 11.0.1 on an M1 Mac, but I don't think that should be a problem. My Xcode version is 12.2 (12B45b).

#### Edit: Big Sur / M1 might be the problem.

I just ran it on the same version of Xcode on my Intel Mac, Catalina 10.15.5, and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use `init(frame: CGRect, 
configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration)` and a non zero frame. ?

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks for the suggestion, but nothing changed. [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-11%20at%2011.54.11%20AM.png)

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 13.4. Which one did you use?

Comment: @Asperi I'm on Xcode 12.2 (12B45b) and iOS 13.0. Also tested on iOS 13.1

Comment: Anyone else have this issue again on Xcode 13.3 & Mac Monterey? I use old Mac with Intel chip. I run on real device 13.5.1 and it crash

I also have this issues on Xcode 13.2.1, After that I updated to 13.3 still face the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is due to a combination of running on an M1 Mac and using an iOS version prior to 14. The problem is known to Apple.

Comment: Hmm, alright then. Hope it gets fixed soon!

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Does anyone have a link to Apple's radar or any place to verify Apple is aware and monitor its resolution?

Comment: The same problem, on xCode Version 12.5 beta not solved this problem

Comment: Cant believe I bought a new M1 because I was worried my 2015 Macbook was about to pack in and wouldn't work for running on ios simulators... ironic!

Comment: @BrandonMedenwald I believe it's radar://FB8920323 but it's not on Open Radar and I'm unaware of how to track progress.

Comment: Really Apple? and now what has to say to my client? I need to buy older MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple workaround.
Setting any of the following diagnostic options in the scheme settings will prevent the crash.

- Address Sanitizer
- Thread Sanitizer
- Malloc Scribble
- Malloc Guard Edges
- Guard Malloc
- Malloc Stack Logging

[Diagnostic Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn8l9.png)

I verified this with Xcode 12.4 (12D4e), iOS 13.7 Simulator, macOS Big Sur 11.2.3（20D91） and M1 Apple Silicon Mac.

Comment: Nice! Does this have any drawbacks? Like hidden console messages or something?

Comment: @aheze As far as I know, there are no drawbacks so far.

Comment: Sounds great. I'll leave the check mark on the current answer, because it's most likely a bug on Apple's part. I voted for your answer though.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, we need to check or uncheck the settings in the scheme?

Comment: @xhinoda Yes, it is. You can avoid the crash by checking any one of the items in the list. Please refer to the linked image of "Diagnostic Options".

Comment: Thanks @Koze , the error go away, but now show only a black screen :(

Answer (score 1):

Your UIViewRepresentable should be a `struct` not a `class`

```swift
struct WebViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
^^^^^^
```

Comment: I changed it but am still getting the error: [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-10%20at%208.12.05%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1):

As not reproducible, just guessing... try different constructors, like

```
let wkWebConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: wkWebConfiguration)
```

or even with some defined frame (anyway it does not matter later for SwiftUI view hierarchy)

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), 
                        configuration: wkWebConfiguration)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I already tried them though, with @Warren Burton's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224739/swiftui-ios-13-uiviewrepresentable-of-wkwebview-gets-thread-1-exc-breakpoint#comment115369493_65224739). I also just tested on my Intel Mac, and my original code works. I think the problem is probably Big Sur or Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 1):

As Norman mentioned it's true if you are using xcode 12 and running simulator having ios version less than 14 it will break the application, it's problem with M1 chip. I my self test the application on 2 systems one on older mac and one on newer mac with m1 chip

Comment: Yeah... M1 is great for speed, but it's a headache for testing devices

Comment: Even you cannot run xcode less than 12 version on M1 chips due to compatibility issue

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is solved with BigSur 11.3

Comment: I'll update today and see if it works. Thanks for posting an answer!