# FIRDLJavaScriptExecuter.m WKWebView crashes on alloc/init

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, wkwebview

[image]

This is the line which caused the crash. I am using XCODE 12.2 with new M1 chip. I have updated the pods as well

Comment: What's your target device OS version?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. It's 13.0

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: no . check this out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224739/swiftui-ios-13-uiviewrepresentable-of-wkwebview-gets-thread-1-exc-breakpoint)